# Is there a way to run the Android emulator in CDMA mode?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need this in order to debug CDMA data (SMS recieved and sent)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by sending commands to your **Android emulator** via **Telnet**.
To begin make sure your android emulator is running, then in a console:
`telnet localhost 5554`.
This will connect you to the emulator (note that the port 5554 may change depending on your setup. This port will be in the title of the emulator.)
Now enter `gsm voice off`. You can also tweak different network parameters; just type `help` for available commands.